# Как написать ORM на это? Вложенный запрос

Tags: django, orm

DELETE FROM news WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100)

Удалить последние 100 записей из таблицы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
last_list = News.objects.order_by('id')[:100]
last_list.delete()
```

Comment: Вау, настолько просто.

Comment: @ArtyomLazovikov да. В консоли вообще в одну строчку можно news.objects.order_by('id')[:100].delete() по идее